# QGIS Dynamic aggerate only features visible in time slice

Tags: qgis, time, spatio-temporal-data, dynamic-text, temporal-controller

I am unable to figure out how to only sum the lengths of the features visible in the map between `@map_start_time` and `@map_end_time`? The aggregation works changing over time but seems to include all features in geographical extent but not temporal extent.
Features have start and end datetimes, DT_Created and UNTIL.

```
aggregate( 'TestLines',  
aggregate:= 'sum', 
expression:=  $length, 
filter:= (intersects(  $geometry, @map_extent )) AND 
(("DT_CREATED">@map_start_time AND
("UNTIL" > @map_start_time OR "UNTIL" < @map_end_time) OR 
 ("DT_CREATED"<@map_start_time AND
("UNTIL" > @map_start_time OR "UNTIL"> @map_end_time) )))
```

seems to complex, must be a more elegant solution, besides this does not appear to work.

** UPDATE
I have further tried to fix the filter and still not luck

```
filter:= (intersects(  $geometry, @map_extent ) AND 
(
  ("DT_CREATED" < @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" > @map_end_time)
 OR 
 ("DT_CREATED" > @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" < @map_end_time)
 OR
 ("DT_CREATED" < @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" > @map_end_time)
 OR
 ("DT_CREATED" > @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" > @map_end_time)
 ))
```

Please any clues to where I have gone wrong?
[image]

Comment: Providing sample data for testing could help. Otherwise, one has to rebuild your project from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression with aggregate function [`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#sum) instead of `aggregate()` - see below for explanation:

```
sum(
    $length,
    filter:=
    intersects ($geometry, @map_extent) and
    (
        (@map_start_time >= "DT_CREATED" and @map_start_time <= "UNTIL") or
        (@map_end_time >=  "DT_CREATED" and @map_end_time <= "UNTIL") or
        (@map_start_time <= "DT_CREATED" and @map_end_time >= "UNTIL")
    )
)
```

*Animated solution: lines are labeled with their length, the large label in the upper left shows the sum of the visible lines: lines A) inside the map canvas and B) lines visible in the current map frame's temporal range. If lines are shifted outside the canvas, they are not included in the sum any more:*
[image]

**Explanation:**

The idea: `@map_start_time` and `@map_end_time` are the start/end of the current frame. Your line starts at `"DT_CREATED"` and stops at `"UNTIL"`. In the following sketch, I have:

- `line1` (starts at `C1`, corresponds to `"DT_CREATED"`, ends at `U1`, corresponds to `"UNTIL"`)
- `line2` (starts at `C2` / `"DT_CREATED"`, ends at `U2` / `"UNTIL"`)
- frame `Fa` (starts at `Sa` / `@map_start_time`, ends at `Ea` / `@map_end_time`)
- frame `Fb` (starts at `Sb` / `@map_start_time`, ends at `Eb` / `@map_end_time`)

Visible are all lines that fully or partially temorally overlap the current frame: during frame `Fa` both `line1` and `line2` are visible, during frame `Fb` only `line2` is visible:

[image]

Frame `Fa` overlaps both `line1` and `line2`, so during the first frame, both lines are visible.

Frame `Fb` overlaps only `line2`, so during this second frame, only one line (`line2`) is visible.

So: if the frame's start-point (`Sa`) is **after**  the line's start point (`C1`), then it must be before the end of the line's end point (`Sa` before `U1`): `Sa >= C1 AND Sa <= U1`. Otherwiese, we have the case of the second frame: `Sb` is after `C1` and after `U1`, so no temporal overlap of the frame `Fb` with `line1`.

Replace the short names given here from `Sa >= C1 AND Sa <= U1` with the fieldnames/variables you have: `@map_start_time >= "DT_CREATED" AND @map_start_time <= "UNTIL"` - this is line 6 in the expression above.

Like this, we determine if the frame's start-point `Sa` (or `Sb`) is inside the temporal range of the line's start/end datetime. This is true for `line1`. It is not true, however, form `line2`. Here, the overlap based on the frame's end-point `Ea`, checking if this is inside the temporal range of our lines. The expression is very similar, we just have to change `@map_start_time` with `@map_end_time` and we get line 7 of the expression above.

There is a third option (not on the sketch): the line's start- and end time is completely within the temporal range of the frame: the frame's start time is before the line's start time and the frame's end time is after the line's end time. This third condition is on line 8 of the expression.

**What went wrong in your expression**

You have as last condition of your updated filter expression (2nd last line):

```
("DT_CREATED" > @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" > @map_end_time)
```

This means: `C3 > Sc` (line starts after frame's start) and `U3 > Ec` (line ends after frame's end) - so this could also be a line that has start- and end-time long after the frame's end, so completely outside the frame's duration:

[image]

Then also you have twice the exactly same condition:

```
("DT_CREATED" < @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" > @map_end_time)
```

This addresses a line with start before and end after the frame's temporal duration: `line4` in the next sketch below.

The last condition you have is:

```
("DT_CREATED" > @map_start_time AND "UNTIL" < @map_end_time)
```

This corresponds to a line with start/end time completely inside the frame's temporal duration: `line5` in the sketch.

What is missing in your expression, however, are conditions for `line6` and `line7`: if only end (6) or start (7) overlap the frame's temporal duration:

[image]

Comment: Fabulous explanation, works a treat and created a truly impactful presentation to principles. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again Babel, a directly related follow up question, how did you create that label, that appears to be geo-stationary?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I used Label Anchoring > Custom... > 30% (or so), see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#placement-for-line-layers , but I don't remember.